# class template of a c style string rvalue type fails to be compiled: returning array error

Tags: c++, class, template-classes

Consider the following template class:

```
//Node.hh
template<class dataType>
class impNode 
{
    private:
    dataType _data;
    public:
    explicit impNode(const dataType &data) { std::cout << "this constructor is called!" << std::endl; };
    virtual ~impNode() { };
    dataType getData() { }; //This is where the error triggers
};
```

Now, when instantiating this class:

```
//main.cpp
int main(int, char**) 
{
    impNode a{98}; 
    impNode b{false};
    impNode c{"hello"};
}
```

I get the following compile time error:

```
error: function returning an array
[build]  27 |  dataType getData() { };
```

One way to avoid this is to specialize the class template:

```
template<>
class impNode<char[6]> 
{
    private:
    public:
    explicit impNode(const char data[6]) { std::cout << "This class template specialization is needed for the program to compile" << std::endl; };
    virtual ~impNode() { };
    char* getData() {  };
};
```

Doing so, the program compiles and runs successfully, being this the output of the program:

```
this constructor is called!
this constructor is called!
This class template specialization is needed for the program to compile
```

However I would like to be able to instantiate the class with any cstyle rvalue string without having to specialize for each different size.

Comment: `return _data;` seems missing..

Comment: @Jarod42 It is indeed true, however that does not has any repercussion on the error described. at least that is what I believe out of my ignorance

Comment: Would wrapping the c-style string in a [std::string_view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) suite your needs? [Example on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/zo7Txn5G6)

Comment: @Brian For the moment given, that is beyond my knowledge, however, I will read about it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just use auto:

```
auto getNode() { return _data; }
```

Comment: About doing this, what would be the return type?

Comment: @Juan_David It would be "decayed" dataType, so same as `std::decay_t<dataType>`. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay . Effectively, for arrays/functions it is a pointer. For other types it is the same type but const/volatile/reference removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a template deduction guide:

```
template<std::size_t N> impNode(char const (&)[N]) -> impNode<char const*>;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/KjTroaooT)

Or if you need to match any type instead of just `char`:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N> impNode(T const (&)[N]) -> impNode<T const*>;
```

However, it might just be easier to make `getData` return a reference:

```
dataType& getData() { };
```

Comment: Now do the same for `wchar_t`, `char8_t`, `char16_t` and `char32_t`